# Telerik Datasource Json Server Paging Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm working on a Hybrid app built with Json data. There's a small problem though. I can't figure out how to get the paging to work for the Datasource.

The json structure looks like this.

```
{
    "respond":1,
    "paging":{
        "stillmore":1,
        "perpage":10,
        "callpage":1,
        "next":2,
        "previous":0,
        "pages":6,
        "result":"52"
    },
    "message":"",
    "result":[
        {Main Data}
    ]
}
```

Here's my DataSource structure

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "JsonURL",
                    dataType: "json",
                    jsonp: "$callback",

                    cache: true

                },
                serverFiltering: true,
                filter: { logic: "paging", filters: [ { field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" } ] },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                     return kendo.stringify(data);
                    if (type == "read") {
                        // send take as "$top" and skip as "$skip"
                        return {
                            $callpage: data.page,
                            $perpage: data.pageSize
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            schema: {
                data: "result", // twitter's response is { "results": [ /* results */ ] }
                total: "paging.result",
                },

            sort: {
                field: "ID",
                dir: "desc"
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            pageSize: 20
        });
```

It's not paging. I have about 100 results, and the server only displays 20 every page. When you want to load the next 20, nothing happens. It gets stuck on the loading gif.

I can't seem to figure it out. How can I enable server paging with this Json return?

Any tips would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Where is the problem? What is behavior of this code?

Comment: It's not paging. I have about 100 results, and the server only displays 20 every page. When you want to load the next 20, nothing happens. It gets stuck on the loading gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in your code in:

```
parameterMap: function (data, type) {
    // DELETE THIS LINE: return kendo.stringify(data);
    if (type == "read") {
        // send take as "$top" and skip as "$skip"
        return {
            callpage: data.page,
            perpage: data.pageSize
        }
    }
}
```

You return `return kendo.stringify(data);` immediately and you can't use your custom binding for page number.

Try to delete this line as I show you above

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the mistake. Still no change though.

Comment: Look in your browser Developer Tool what request was sent for each page and what is the result. Is it correct?

Comment: It's almost correct. It's inserting %24 in front of the request. It looks like this: `https://example.com/api/getposts/?custom_post=job_listing&%24callpage=1&%24perpage=20` it should be this: `https://example.com/api/getposts/?custom_post=job_listing&callpage=1&perpage=20`

Comment: Try to `return {
            callpage: data.page,
            perpage: data.pageSize
        }`  Without dollar sign